# Flask SQLAlchemy Filter On A Postgres JSON List Object Based on a Single String

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model called Testing. The field called `alias` is a JSON field (a list really) and has values such as `["a", "b"]` or `["d", "e"]` and so on.

```
class Testing(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'testing'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(25))
    alias = db.Column(JSON)

    def __init__(self, name, alias):
        self.name = name
        self.alias = alias
```

In my flask view I grab a url parameter that I want to use to filter Testing to get all Testing objects in which the parameter value is in the `alias` json list. So for example if `url_param_value="a"` I want all the Testing objects where `"a"` is in `alias`. So the `alias` value of `["a", "b"]` would be a hit in this example.

Here is my approach but its not working and I assume it has to do with seralization.

```
Testing.query.filter(Testing.alias.contains(url_param_val)).all()
```

I am getting the below error

```
NotImplementedError: Operator 'contains' is not supported on this expression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` field is a JSON type, not an array type. JSON columns don't have a `contains` method, even if you happen to be storing array data (how would the database know?)

In Postgres, you can use [`json_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html) to expand a JSON array to a set of JSON values; this will return one row per element:

```
select id, json_array_elements(alias) as val from testing;

   id    |         val
---------+--------------------
 1       | "a"
 2       | "b"
```

You can use that as a subquery to select records that contain a matching value:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.alias, cast(q.val as varchar)
from testing t, (
    select id, json_array_elements(alias) as val
    from testing
) q
where q.id=t.id and cast(q.val as varchar) = '"a"';
```

In SQLAlchemy syntax:

```
subq = session.query(
    Testing.id,
    func.json_array_elements(Testing.alias).label("val")
).subquery()
q = session.query(Testing).filter(
    cast(subq.c.val, sa.Unicode) == '"a"',
    subq.c.id == Testing.id)
```

Warning: this is going to be very inefficient for large tables; you're probably better off fixing the types to match your data, and then creating appropriate indexes.